# switch HTML5 video source based on body_class

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html5-video

I'm working on a Wordpress site that has an HTML5 video background. I'm trying to get the video to alternate between two options depending on the page - for example if I have 4 pages, pages 1,3 would show video A and 2,4 would show video B.

Whats the easiest way to do this? I've had a bit of a play but can't think of a way to just use CSS and the body_class of each page, I don't think you can change the  of something in a  tag with CSS. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

My php and js skills are pretty limited but I'm happy to have a bash at getting something to work if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: what do you mean, body_class? is it class attribute of body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert this code before closing body tag : `</body>` :

```
<script>

    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]

    switch ( document.body.className ) {

        case 1 : video.src = 'a.mp4'; break;
        case 2 : video.src = 'b.mp4'; break;
        case 3 : video.src = 'a.mp4'; break;
        case 4 : video.src = 'b.mp4'; break;

    }

</script>
```

So if body has attribute class, and it's value 1 or 3 the video a will be shown, something like that.

Comment: Thank-you this is fantastic. I really need to brush up on my js. One quick follow-up: I have both .mp4 and .webm sources for compatibility, what is the correct syntax for adding those in? can I simply have 

video.src = 'a.mp4','a.webm'; break;

Comment: I would recomend .webm because more browsers support it. But the best solution would be to include multiple `source` tags inside of your video with different video sources.

Comment: Sorry my question was poorly phrased and structured! I mean to say: I have multiple sources currently in the html, my snippet looks like this:  
 `<video id="videobcg" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0">
 
 <source src="a.webm" type="video/webm" codecs="vp8, vorbis">
 <source src="a.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <img src="a.jpg" title="Your browser does not support the <video> tag" />
</video>`

I'm wondering what the correct syntax for changing both the .webm and .mp4 using the js you provided is

Comment: `var mp4 = video.childern[0]; var webm = video.children[1]` then just change the src of mp4 and webm instead of video